# Attacks on server-side web

Tags: attacks, webserver

What types of attacks are specific for server-side web, but not client-side?
From what I have found on the Web the most attacks focus on client-side rather than server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf), most issues are server-side:

- A1 Injection: SQL Injection, Command Injection, etc.
- A2 Broken Authentication
- A3 Sensitive Data Exposure
- A4 XXE
- A5 Broken Access Control (OWASP places eg directory traversal here, as well as IDOR, privilege escalation, etc)
- A6 Security Misconfiguration (mostly server-side)
- A8 Insecure Deserialization
- A9 Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities (mostly server-side)
- A10 Insufficient Logging & Monitoring

They also list some server-side issues under "Additional risks to consider" such as unrestricted file upload, application-level DOS, or SSRF.

The only issue that could be classified as client-site is:

- A7 XSS

OWASP doesn't list a lot of client-site issues though. Some, such as CSRF, Open Redirect, or Clickjacking are listed under additional risks. OWASP also places some issues that are exploited client-side in the above categories (eg CORS issues under broken access control).

Note also that while XSS is often considered a client-side issue, [classification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/is-xss-a-server-side-or-client-side-vulnerability/73698) isn't that easy, as the vulnerability itself is mostly introduced server-side.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Injection would be an example of a server-side attack because the code that is "injected" is run on the SQL server.

Comment: Could you expand this answer to include a few more examples of server side web app attacks?

Answer (score 0):

There are several attacks varying form CSRF, DDOS, Website defacement, etc. The best place to get idea of the top attacks is OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) project site:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

They update and maintain the top threats and recommendations on mitigation. You may refer the Top 10 threats on following link form the project site:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10

Answer (score 0):

[Exploit Db](https://www.exploit-db.com/) can also give you idea about both client side and server side vulnerabilities. Its **Web Application Exploits** section could be useful for you.  Therefore, you may have idea about the attack types. I would look for found vulnerabilities in both client side and server side frameworks.  For server side ( back-end ) frameworks; You can check on Exploit-DB and also in other websites with the keywords of server side frameworks; Example: ASP.NET, Ruby On Rails, PHP.